# "other" storage in Mac is 27gbs after clean install of BigSur beta

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I downloaded and installed macOS Big Sur beta. I did a clean install and in my storage I have 14gbs used by the system and the "other" is taking 27gbs and I can't seem to find out what is taking so much space given there is nothing installed on the computer and most of my stuff is backed on iCloud. I looked around in terminal for a bit and 17gbs is taken by cloudKit, is it safe to delete CloudKit. The CloudKit is located here

```
 /Users/vibhorsagar/Library/Caches
```

so idk if I can delete it. but is there any other way to find out what is taking that much storage?
Since I only have 128gbs ssd, every gig matters.

Comment: "most of my stuff is backed on iCloud" iCloud is not a backup solution, it is a synchronisation solution. Delete from one device, it will delete from all devices.

Comment: @Tetsujin i know that. storage in the icloud isnt the problem, its the space taken up on my physical ssd labeled  as “other”. which is what i cant figure out what it is.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space